# Cascade All not deleting

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Please check this Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "css_empresa")
public class Empresa extends EntidadContactable implements Serializable,
    Convert {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "EMPRESA_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = ConstantesSecuencias.SEQ_EMPRESA, allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EMPRESA_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "cod_empresa", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;


@Column(name = "num_ruc", precision = 13)
private BigDecimal numRuc;

@Column(name = "num_rup", precision = 15)
private BigDecimal numRup;

@Column(name = "txt_direccion_web", length = 255)
private String txtDireccionWeb;

@Column(name = "txt_nombre", nullable = false, length = 255)
private String txtNombre;

@Column(name = "txt_observaciones", length = 255)
private String txtObservaciones;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cod_usuario")
private Usuario administrador;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to DireccionEmpresa
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<DireccionEmpresa> direccionEmpresas;

    //Getters Setters ommited for brevity
    }
```

Then in my controller I have something like this:

```
Empresa empresa=entityManager.findById(1L);
empresa.getDireccionEmpresas.remove(direccionEmpresa);
entityManager.merge(empresa);
```

However this is not deleting the DireccionEmpresa from the Database... why this could be happening?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's normal. You didn't remove empresa, so there's nothing to cascade. You only removed direccionEmpresa from the corresponding collection. You have to delete the object manually.

[another question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011519/jpa-onetomany-not-deleting-child) which explains the case pretty well.

JPA 2 added orphanRemoval attribute which should take care of removing child objects when you remove them from parent's collection. So in your case it would be:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<DireccionEmpresa> direccionEmpresas;

//Getters Setters ommited for brevity
}
```

Comment: +1. I would also add that the call to merge is unnecessary: the entities are attached.