# cascading delete in playframework-how to model the Entities

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, cascade

While creating an online shop application using `play-1.2.4` ,I ran into some problems with jpa..I wanted to provide an admin area using the `CRUD module` in play.Here ,an admin user can create/edit or delete the entities in the application(like `Customer`s,`Order`s,`Item`s etc).

A `Customer` can create Orders.Each `Order` will have a Set of `CartItem`s.When an `Order` is deleted,the corresponding `CartItem`s must be deleted.When a `Customer` is deleted,all his Orders must be deleted as well.I thought I could get this by setting the `cascade` property in jpa annotation.

I modelled it like this

***Customer.java***

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends Model {
    @Email
    @Required
    public String email;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Order> orders;
    @OneToOne
    public PayMethod currentPayment;
    ...
}
```

***Order.java***

```
@Entity
public class Order extends Model {  
    @OneToMany( cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<CartItem> cartItems;

    @ManyToOne
    public Customer customer;
    @ManyToOne
    public PayMethod paymentMethod;
    ...
}
```

***CartItem.java***

```
@Entity
public class CartItem extends Model implements Comparable<CartItem>{    
    @ManyToOne
    public Item item;
    public int quantity;
}
```

***PayMethod.java***

```
@Entity
public class PayMethod extends Model {
    @Required
    public String cardNumber;
    @ManyToOne
    public Customer customer;
    ...
}
```

The following database tables were created

***customer table***

```
id |  email      |   fullname    | currentpayment_id
---|-------------|---------------|-----------------
2  |jon@gmail.com| jon           |29
```

***order table***

```
 id |customer_id | paymentmethod_id 
----+------------+-----------------
 25 |  2         |       29
```

***cartitem table***

```
id  | quantity | item_id 
----+----------+---------
 26 |        1 |      14
```

***order_cartitem table***

```
 order_id | cartitems_id 
----------+--------------
       25 |           26
```

In the Admin interface created using CRUD(I haven't implented any methods ,just using the provided CRUD module as is),I tried to delete a Customer,but then,I get this error,

```
ERROR: update or delete on table "cartitem" violates foreign key constraint "fk7ff437ad3e28aa91" on table "order_cartitem"
Detail: Key (id)=(26) is still referenced from table "order_cartitem".
08:03:03,031 ERROR ~ Could not synchronize database state with session
```

Is there something wrong with the way I modelled the Entities? I thought the delete on the `Customer` will be cascaded to `Order` and that in turn will cascade to its `CartItem`s .

What do I have to do to get this cascading effect?Or do I have to manually remove each contained instances of `CartItem`s?

**EDIT:** As per Seb's reply

```
class Order extends Model { 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<CartItem> cartItems;
    ...
}

class CartItem extends Model implements Comparable<CartItem>{

    @ManyToOne
    public Item item;

    public int quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    public Order order;
...
}

static void addItemToCart(Long itemId,Long orderId,String quantity) {
    Item item = Item.findById(itemId);
   Order order = Order.findById(orderId);
   int qty = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
   CartItem cartItem = new CartItem(item,qty);
   cartItem.order=order;
   order.addItem(cartItem, qty);
   order.save();
...
}
```

This gets rid of **order_cartitem** table and adds a field **order_id** to **cartitem table**

***cartitem table***

```
     id | quantity | item_id | order_id 
    ----+----------+---------+----------
     26 |        1 |      14 |       25    
     27 |        1 |      20 |       25
```

The `admin(CRUD)` interface,lists the `Customer`s and `Order`s.When a particular `Customer`(the one who created the `Order`) is selected and the delete button is clicked,it results in a `JPA error`

```
JPA error
A JPA error occurred (Cannot commit): collection owner not associated with session: models.Order.cartItems
```

here is the [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/r42mPEdB)

If someone can understand why this is happening,please tell me.

Interestingly,I can click on the `delete button` for a particular `Order`,and it successfully calls the following controller method,

***Admin.java***

```
public static void deleteOrder(Long id) {
    Order order = Order.findById(id);
    order.delete();     
    ...
}
```

which deletes the `Order` and all its `CartItem`s successfully..
So,why does this not happen when a `Customer` is deleted?

Comment: Code looks ok to me. Perhaps this thread helps a bit to find the cause of the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011519/jpa-onetomany-not-deleting-child

Comment: thanks for the great link..will go thru it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your relation bidirectionnal by adding this to your cartitem class

```
@ManyToOne
public Order order;
```

and a mappedBy="order" in your cartItems @OneToMany

then hibernate will better handles your deletion. I am guessing that without this bidirectionnal link, hibernate tried to firstly set the column to null. You can also try to allow null values in your join table to see what happens if you don't want to enable the bidirectional relationship

Comment: thanks for the reply..I tried this,Now ,when I tried to remove a Customer through CRUD(Admin),I got this error:  ERROR ~ an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: collection owner not associated with session: models.Order.cartItems

Comment: cascade deletion in hibernate is a bit tricky. I must admit that I never really understand all the cases and do some empiric tests to find the solution. Orphan removal is very touchy because hibernate need a custom collection implementation. You can try without it. You may also try with eager fetching between customer and order but this may not be the best solution in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with cascade properties of JPA. Try to use related cascade annotations from hibernate and remove all of cascades you used from JPA. Here is an example for your PayMethod model class:

```
// Be careful, import the realted annotations from hibernate (not JPA)
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

@Entity
public class PayMethod extends Model {
    @Required
    public String cardNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public Customer customer;
    ...
}
```

Above method works for me with uni-directional mapping. I hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I was not using a List, I was using an entities' array.

The problem with my wrapping entity was that it did not initialized the array (new MyEntity[0]) as I usually do with my lists (new ArrayList(0)).

I realized (empirical method) that when trying to call "merge" to a "null" array associated by an "all-delete-orphan" relationship, the "org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: collection owner not associated with session:" arose.

So my piece of advice is: when using a "all-delete-orphans" relationship, initialize your collection (array included) with an empty instance.