# Hibernate @OneToMany remove child from list when updating parent

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, associations, one-to-many

I have the following entities:

TEAM

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Team {
[..]
private Set<UserTeamRole> userTeamRoles;

/**
 * @return the userTeamRoles
 */
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<UserTeamRole> getUserTeamRoles() {
    return userTeamRoles;
}

/**
 * @param userTeamRoles
 *            the userTeamRoles to set
 */
public void setUserTeamRoles(Set<UserTeamRole> userTeamRoles) {
    this.userTeamRoles = userTeamRoles;
}
```

}

and

USER_TEAM_ROLE

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_team_role")
public class UserTeamRole {

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "FK_TeamId")
 public Team getTeam() {
    return team;
 }
}
```

Now, when updating a Team entity that contains for example Team.userTeamRoles = {UTR1, UTR2} with {UTR1, UTR3}, I want UTR2 to be deleted. But the way I do it now, the old list remains the same and it only adds UTR3 to the list.

This is how I do it at the moment:

```
 if (!usersDualListData.getTarget().isEmpty()) {
        // the role for each user within the team will be "employee"
        team.setUserTeamRoles(new HashSet<UserTeamRole>());
        Role roleForUser = roleService
                .getRoleByName(RoleNames.ROLE_EMPLOYEE.name());
        for (User user : usersDualListData.getTarget()) {
            UserTeamRole utr = new UserTeamRole();
            utr.setUser(user);
            utr.setTeam(team);
            utr.setRole(roleForUser);
            team.getUserTeamRoles().add(utr);
        }
    }

teamService.updateTeam(team);
```

I thought that by doing `team.setUserTeamRoles(new HashSet<UserTeamRole>());` the list would be reset and because of the cascades the previous list would be deleted.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think is the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011519/jpa-onetomany-not-deleting-child check it out!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

1. Instead of replacing the collection (`team.setUserTeamRoles(new HashSet<UserTeamRole>());`) you have to `clear()` the existing one. This happens because if Hibernate loads the entity (and its collections) from DB, it "manages" them, ie. tracks their changes. Generally when using Hibernate it's better **not** to create any setters for collections (lists, sets). Create only the getter, and clear the collection returned by it, ie:

   `team.getUserTeamRoles().clear();`
2. Another thing is that you miss orphan deletion (ie. delete child object when it's removed from collection in the parent). To enable it, you need to add `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)` in owning entity.

Comment: @Adam Dyga Hibernate noob here, could you explain more on why it's better not to create any setters for collections?

Comment: @Jonny try to replace a collection in an entity with an new one (eg. new ArrayList()) and see what happens on save ;)

Comment: Thanks for clear answer. But can I do same trick if I recreated parent object using `new` keyword and manually inserted ID to it (i.e. object is not "managed" by Hibernate and it in Transient state)?

Comment: @MyTitle why would you like to do something like that?

Comment: please, check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057678/hibernate-remove-on-update-child-list?noredirect=1#comment29893886_20057678

Comment: @MyTitle I don't fully understand what you mean by "recreating the parent". But if it's a new entity (transient), it's not managed by Hibernate, so you may overwrite the child collection.

Comment: if someone it's so kind to take a look at my question, i would be very happy, because i can't build correct equals / hashCode methods for a many-to-many relationship. thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737145/equals-and-hashcode-of-these-entities-spring-mvc-hibernate