# Hibernate one to many relationship removing child object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

i have a simple one to many mapping in my project...let's suppose that i have 1 father object and 3 child objects stored in my DB.
the problem  occurs when i load the father object and change the number of sons (for example removing one of them). When i try to update the father object, the son that is no longer in the child's set it's still on the DB.
Is there a way to delete the unwanted child without have to manually proceed?

Comment: Is the "Cascade" option set to "all" on the collection?

Comment: I think this link might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686595/hibernate-onetomany-remove-child-from-list-when-updating-parent Have a look, change to your need according..

Comment: You need "delete orphans". Cascade means that when creating the the parent, the child is created too, when removing the parent, the child is removed too and so on. Nobody ever said that when you remove the child from the list, that it is removed from the DB.

Comment: yep...and it's also set the "mappedBy" parameter

Comment: @Jayesh so to just remove one item from the list using `.clear()` command i have to copy the list, clear it and then manually re-add all'items ?? not very practicle

Comment: @Medioman92 Why `clear()` the list? Just remove the entity you want to remove from the list and delete it from the database? No need to clear the whole list and re-populate it again.

Comment: @Magnilex i'm working only with the father object (the update method is called on this object)...if possibile i'd like to avoid the need of working with children object

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attribute `orphanRemoval=true` on the @OneToMany annotation.

Comment: i'm using JPA annotations...no "orphanRemoval" option avaible :(

Comment: Ok. I think with pure JPA, it is not possible. I suggest you to indicate de JPA "restriction" in your question ;-)