# Hibernate. Remove on update child list

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I have standard `@ManyToOne` association in Hibernate. When updating, I'm creating new entity (using `new` keyword) and fill it with necessary values (ID also inserted). Values comes from UI. In same way I create new collection of child objects, fill each of them by values (ID also inserted), and store collection in parent object (using setter or by `addAll()` method).

So my question is: how I can remove all objects in parent collection when updating parent, and replace them by new collection. In new collection some objects are really new and some only need to be updated (they have inserted ID).

I learned about `orhanRemoval`, but it can't help, because parent object must be in "managed" state (so `clear()` on child collection will not work), not in transient state as in my example..

Comment: You create parent, create children, populate parent with children, what after that. You said parent is transient. How do you save collection in this case? I don't understand this from your description.

Comment: @mvb13 yes, parent is in transient state. I just add child list to parent and save parent (cascade operations work nice). But I want to remove old collection from parent (and from DB), and replace it with new one (which I added to newly create transient parent)

Comment: If you save parent this means that it is no transient, it must be persisted or detached. If it is in detached state reattach it, than use orphan removal, this is the case when you should use it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you are updating then you should fetch the existing entities from DB, modify them, and commit. You shouldn't create a new object each time by using `new` and setting the ID.

Comment: @AdamDyga ok, thanks. It's mean every time I need to update object I should retrieve entity, populate it with new values from UI and call `Session#saveOrupdate`?

Comment: @MyTitle yes. What's more, if you update existing entity you don't have to pass it to update() or saveOrUpdate(), it will be automatically saved on transaction commit. It works this way because Hibernate manages all entities fetched in the session and automatically detects and flushes changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *update* or *saveOrUpdate()* method does not take care the current status of the object inside the database, instead it updates all current attributes of the object. Therefore in your case, when you update the new object with its collection, it does not take care the old collection and it will update the new collection of the object. Hence, you have both the old collection and the new collection inside the database.

To overwrite the old collection by the new one, you should use the *merge()* method, which at first it loads the object with the same id into the persistence context, then it copies the state of the detached object to the persistent one, then it considers if the object is dirty. If so, it will persists the new object with changes.

The following code may demonstrate the above explanation:

```
    // Initial the persistent layer
    DAOLayer daoLayer = new DAOLayer();

    // Persist the parent object with 1 child
    Parent parent = new Parent("parent");
    parent.addChild(new Child("child"));
    Parent persistentParent = daoLayer.merge(parent);

    // Create the new parent object with the same Id stored in DB
    Parent newParent = new Parent("parent");
    newParent.setId(persistentParent.getId());
    newParent.addChild(new Child("child"));

    // Update the new parent object
    persistentParent = daoLayer.merge(newParent);
```

The above code results in 1 child in the database. If you change the merge() method to the saveOrUpdate() method, it results in 2 children in the database.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. But nevertheless what way is more preferable in my case from your point of view:

1. Explicitly creating new entity, insert ID to it, update it with new values and then use `merge()`

2. Use `get()` to retrieve entity (within transaction) and update retrieved entity with new values (hibernate will auto-flush changes)

Comment: It depends on the way you manage entities. If you retrieve the object, send it to UI, then the UI change that object, it's more suitable to use merge() method since you don't need to check which attributes have been changed. But in the case you propose some fields in Web (e.g. search criteria), you know exactly which ones you want to change, you can load the persistent entity and change it. From my point of view, I prefer to use the merge() method. And it is also the standard method in JPA (JPA does not support update() and saveOrUpdate() methods).

Comment: This seems to work with the exception of a <many-to-one unique="true"> relation. i assume its because of the no support for delete-orphan?