# Replace entity's list instead of adding to it when updating

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

FooObject has an entity with a few lists of bar objects managed by entities. Whenever I edit FooObject and call update on it, all of those lists are added to, not replaced.

```
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
              mappedBy = "barEntity", targetEntity = BarTypeAEntity.class)
   private List<BarTypeAEntity> barTypeAs;
```

I can first remove all the lists before calling update but in auditing these tables it appears as a delete then an new creation, rather than just one update.

How can I just simply overwrite rather than append these lists

Comment: Can you post BarTypeEntity class? Can you post the code where you are updating the FooObject.?

Comment: For auditing do you use the EmptyInterceptor ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `orphanRemoval = true`. This tells Hibernate that if you remove `BarTypeAEntity` object from the collection of `barTypeAs`and then save `FooObject`, the removed `BarTypeAEntity`should be deleted from the underlying DB.

```
@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
              mappedBy = "barEntity", targetEntity = BarTypeAEntity.class,
              orphanRemoval = true )

private List<BarTypeAEntity> barTypeAs;
```

And do something like this for update

```
foo.getBarTypeAs().clear();
foo.getBarTypeAs().add(new BarTypeAEntity());
```

Comment: I also found the same solution here, with slightly more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686595/hibernate-onetomany-remove-child-from-list-when-updating-parent The only problem with this solution is auditing - my bar entities are shown as deleted then created again.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, can't got you with "auditing"

Comment: y orpanRemoval = true? can you explain?