# What is @Fetch annotation in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORU_OAUTH_ID", nullable = false)
@OrderBy("ORU_ORDER ")
private List<RedirectedURLs> acceptedReturnUrls;
```

1. In this code i want to understand what @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) does ?
2. what is the difference between orphanRemoval and CascadeType.DELETE ?

Answer (score 3):

1. If this
   [link](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/)
   can help you.

   2. For CascadingType.DELETE and orphanRemoval

> **Cascading Remove**
>
> Marking a reference field with CascadeType.REMOVE (or CascadeType.ALL,
>   which includes REMOVE) indicates that remove operations should be
>   cascaded automatically to entity objects that are referenced by that
>   field (multiple entity objects can be referenced by a collection
>   field):
>
> ```
> @Entity
> class Employee {
>      :
>     @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
>     private Address address;
>      :
> }
> ```
>
> **Orphan Removal**
>
> JPA 2 supports an additional and more aggressive remove cascading mode which can be specified using the orphanRemoval element of the
>   @OneToOne and @OneToMany annotations:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> class Employee {
>      :
>     @OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true)
>     private Address address;
>      :
> }
> ```
>
> **DIFFERENCE:-**
>
> The difference between the two settings is in the response to disconnecting a relationship. For example, such as when setting the
>   address field to null or to another Address object.
>
> - If orphanRemoval=true is specified the disconnected Address instance    is automatically removed. This is useful for cleaning up
>     dependent    objects (e.g. Address) that should not exist without a
>     reference from    an owner object (e.g. Employee).
> - If only cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE is specified no automatic action    is taken since disconnecting a relationship is not a remove 
>     operation.

(Cascading Remove and Delete are synonyme)

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18813411/7700481).

Comment: Personally I don't like orphanRemoval, the code is often easier to read if the remove operation is explicit, and you avoid the additional overhead (JPA has to traverse to discover orphans).

Comment: Thank you so much its really helpful.

Comment: This is not entirely true - `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE` does have an impact on db - it removes the foreign key. What sense would it have, if there was no action?