# JPA: delete parent with related children

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat",
    uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_1", "user_2"})
    })
public class Chat {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_1")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_2")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user2;
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users",
  uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"company_id", "username"})
  }
 )
public class User {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-gen", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-gen",strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    // there is no field/reference to Chat entity
}
```

And User entity without any references to Chat entity. I need to remove user with it's chats. Problem is that user id (that I want to remove) could be either in `user1` or `user2` field. For example, I have user A and user B. They have chat C. And if I try to remove, for example, user A, it should remove user A and chat C. But with provided configuration, I have following error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`mydb`.`chat`, CONSTRAINT `FKqslncg7pcc89gvjjpp9jypbha` 
FOREIGN KEY (`user_2`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
```

As possible solution I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7200221/2114952). But using of

```
entityManager.remove(user); 
entityManager.clear();
```

does not help. Also, I checked ddl code and there is no any mention of Cascade actions. 
How to fix this?

Comment: You mean when you delete the parent, all the related "dependent" entities must be deleted too, if that is the case, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813341/what-is-the-difference-between-cascade-and-orphan-removal-from-db)
using orphanRemoval

Comment: @MahmoudAlSiksek, this won't help. I use different annotations and I don't have references to children in parent class

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The first thing that you need is to add the human-readable ForeignKey constraint and remove `@OnDelete`. Now my code looks like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_1", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "user_1_fk"))
private User user1;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_2", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "user_2_fk"))
private User user2;
```

Then I dropped this table, launched an application to allow hibernate re-create this table with proper FK names provided in annotations. Then I opened MySQL workbench and modified foreign keys for this table using following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE chat DROP FOREIGN KEY `user_1_fk`;
ALTER TABLE chat DROP FOREIGN KEY `user_2_fk`;
ALTER TABLE chat
   ADD CONSTRAINT `user_1_fk`
   FOREIGN KEY (`user_1` )
   REFERENCES `users` (`id` )
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE chat
   ADD CONSTRAINT `user_2_fk`
   FOREIGN KEY (`user_2` )
   REFERENCES `users` (`id` )
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

That's all.