# JPA foreign key constraint with CascadeType.ALL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities

That's first entity

```
public class Manager {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<ExpertAndRequest> requests;

    // ...

}
```

Second entity. This is the binding table of the two entities.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "SOME_TABLE_NAME")
@IdClass(ExpertAndRequestId.class)
public class ExpertAndRequest implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long managerId;

    @Id
    private Long requestId;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "managerId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Manager manager;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "requestId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ParticipantRequest request;



}
```

So I delete the data from the table

```
this.managerRepository.delete(manager);
```

And I get exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**:

I updated class above.

This is the IdClass

```
@Data
public class ExpertAndRequestId implements Serializable {

    private long managerId;
    private long requestId;


    public int hashCode() {
        return (int)(managerId + requestId);
    }

    public String toString() {

        return String.format("ExpertAndRequestId [expert = \"%s\", request=\"%s\"]", this.managerId, this.requestId);

    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof ExpertAndRequestId) {
            ExpertAndRequestId otherId = (ExpertAndRequestId) object;
            return (otherId.requestId == this.requestId) && (otherId.managerId == this.managerId);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The third entity

```
public class ParticipantRequest {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<ExpertAndRequest> experts;

    // ...

}
```

Example I took from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

Answer (score 1):

As you have a bidirectional relation between the Parent-Entity `Manager` and the Child-Entity `ExpertAndRequest` what you need is a `CascadeType.REMOVE` (or CascadeType.ALL, which includes REMOVE): You say to Hibernate "if the parent entity is removed please remove the child entity too". 
Take a llo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813341/what-is-the-difference-between-cascade-and-orphan-removal-from-db) to understand how to use both `CascadeType.REMOVE` and `orphanRemoval`

Answer (score 0):

try `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}` instead of `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` and take [this site](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-bidirectional-many-many-association/) as reference.