# Delete both objects with Cascade.Remove in OneToOne

Tags: java, spring, jpa, cascade

The database contains two tables of requests and responses. The request identifier is also the identifier in the responses. When deleting responses, I should also delete the request with the corresponding id. In my case deleting one entry does not delete another

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "someShema", name = "request")
public class RequestDto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "request_id")
    private Long requestId;
........

}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "someShema", name = "response")
public class ResponseDto {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "request_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name="property", value="request"))
    private Long requestId;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "request_id")
    private RequestDto request;



 @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM ResponseDto r WHERE r.requestId= :id")
    void deleteResponseAndRequest(@Param("id") long id);
```

Unfortunately many of the examples did not solve the problem, for example this [Spring JPA OneToOne FK as PK Cascade.Remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267954/spring-jpa-onetoone-fk-as-pk-cascade-remove)

Comment: Can you please add the code you use to delete the response? Do you get any exception or just the response is deleted without any other sign.

Comment: Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31471415). I think you have same problem.

Comment: @gmanjon added a delete method. Jpa remove record from response without any error

Comment: JPA delete queries are one off database queries that run in the database, so they don't use the entity mapping model. Delete queries (AKA bulk deletes) are efficient because they assume you know what you are doing - so avoid reading in the entity model, which is required to figure out what references it needs to cascade over. If you want delete to cascade over mappings, you must call em.remove on the entity directly - or use spring remove api on an entity instance.