# Hibernate ommit the JsonManagedReference to persist

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to persist one object which has inside list.
I had to annotate the entity Item with     @JsonManagedReference
and ItemProperty with    @JsonBackReference, to avoid infinite loop - break the cycle.

And for getting items with item properties is fine. The problem is now when I try to persist the new Item with list of item properties, then only the Item is persisted, without any ItemProperties. Any one know why's that? Has the    @JsonBackReference/ManagedReference annotations something with it?

CODE:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "type")
private ItemType itemType;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
// @JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference which gets serialized normally.
@JsonManagedReference
private List<ItemProperty> itemProperties;

public Item() {

}

public Item(ItemType itemType, List<ItemProperty> itemProperties) {
    this.itemType = itemType;
    this.itemProperties = itemProperties;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ItemType getItemType() {
    return itemType;
}

public void setItemType(ItemType itemType) {
    this.itemType = itemType;
}

public List<ItemProperty> getItemProperties() {
    return itemProperties;
}

public void setItemProperties(List<ItemProperty> itemProperties) {
    this.itemProperties = itemProperties;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Item{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", itemType=" + itemType +
            ", itemProperties=" + itemProperties +
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Item item = (Item) o;
    return id == item.id &&
            itemType == item.itemType &&
            Objects.equals(itemProperties, item.itemProperties);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, itemType, itemProperties);
}
}
```

ITEM PROPERTY:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item_properties")
public class ItemProperty {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
@JsonBackReference
private Item item;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_property_definition_id")
private ItemPropertyDefinition itemPropertyDefinition;

@Column(name = "value")
private String value;

public ItemProperty(){}

public ItemProperty(Item item, ItemPropertyDefinition itemPropertyDefinition, String value) {
    this.item = item;
    this.itemPropertyDefinition = itemPropertyDefinition;
    this.value = value;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Item getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(Item item) {
    this.item = item;
}

public ItemPropertyDefinition getItemPropertyDefinition() {
    return itemPropertyDefinition;
}

public void setItemPropertyDefinition(ItemPropertyDefinition itemPropertyDefinition) {
    this.itemPropertyDefinition = itemPropertyDefinition;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ItemProperty{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", item=" + item +
            ", itemPropertyDefinition=" + itemPropertyDefinition +
            ", value='" + value + '\'' +
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    ItemProperty that = (ItemProperty) o;
    return id == that.id &&
            Objects.equals(item, that.item) &&
            Objects.equals(itemPropertyDefinition, that.itemPropertyDefinition) &&
            Objects.equals(value, that.value);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, item, itemPropertyDefinition, value);
}
```

}

IN REST CONTROLLER:

```
   @PostMapping("/items")
Item addItem(@RequestBody Item item) {
    item.setId(0);
    return this.itemService.addItem(item);
}
```

Thanks in advance for hints.

Have a nice day and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven´t declared the cascade flag in the @OneToMany. By default no operation on an item entity is cascaded to the ItemProperty list. So take a look into the CascadeType enum and set the operations you want to be cascaded to the itemsproperty list. For more information on CascadeTypes look [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/).

Example:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item", orphanRemoval = true)
// @JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference which gets serialized normally.
@JsonManagedReference
private List<ItemProperty> itemProperties;
```

If you wonder what´s the orphanRemoval good for take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18813341/7634201).

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me. Maybe my body I put to request is bad?

Comment: {
        "id": null,
        "itemType": "SKI",
        "itemProperties": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "itemPropertyDefinition": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "propertyName": "model",
                    "itemType": "SKI"
                },
                "value": "Head 3.0"
            },
]}

Comment: and in DAO i have only:
@Override
    public Item addItem(Item item) {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(item);
        return item;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The C.Weber answer was right but also @Transactional annotation was missing.