# Hibernate OneToMany cascade

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I've created two entities with a OneToMany relationship but when I remove the parent manually from the database the children remain. I've tried different solutions but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    public List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;

}
```

I've tried different solutions like the one attached below, but for some reason when i delete the parent manually through commands the children remain after the parent was removed.

[What is the difference between cascade and orphan removal from DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813341/what-is-the-difference-between-cascade-and-orphan-removal-from-db)

Comment: "i delete the parent manually **through commands**" - what you mean by that?

Comment: I am testing it through SQL commands on the console rather than through application API if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you mean you are running SQL command manually to delete?

Comment: Given the fact that you delete the parent not through hibernate, it is not possible for hibernate to cascade the delete operations. Also it seems that your `CascadeType` should be `CascadeType.DELETE`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you may recheck your database tables. There should be a 'PARENT_ID' column in the 'CHILD' table. Which will prevent deleting a parent without deleting respective children by giving a foreign key violation error related to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your table structure for tables PARENT and CHILD in the database. There should be a foreign key reference to parent_id in the CHILD table and on delete cascade property set.

As per your models, there is no relationship from child to parent and hence the delete of parent is not cascading the child.
You can either create bidirectional relationship by adding @ManyToOne relationship from child to parent
or use @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) property after specifying unidirectional @ManyToOne relationship from child side.