# JPA modeling failed to persist collection updates

Tags: java, jpa

I have a problem to implement the following data diagram with JPA that represent IAM model.

[image]

See JPA entities that implement this model in the bottom of this post.
`IamPermission`, `IamRole` work well but not `IamRoleMember`.

Considering initial database state describe bellow, and the code of `UpdateIamMembersOfIamRoleServiceImpl`, when I try to update role members, by adding `group2@mycompany.com` to the list of Iam role members, it works: JPA do the diff and understand it has to insert `group2@mycompany.com` to `iam_role_members` table,

BUT

when I try to update role members, by adding `group2@mycompany.com` and removing `group1@mycompany.com` from the list of Iam role members, I get the following error:
`org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.mdm.security.mdmiam.iamrole.domain.IamRole.iamRoleMembers`.

Any one can help to make it what I expect: delete `group1@mycompany.com` and add `group2@mycompany.com` to `iam_role_members` table?

Thanks !

Pierre.

**iam_permissions**

```
+--------------------+  
|                 id |  
+--------------------+  
| domain.data.get    |  
| domain.data.update |
+--------------------+
```

**iam_roles**

```
+--------------------+  
|                 id |  
+--------------------+  
| domain.dataViewer  |  
+--------------------+
```

**iam_role_members**

```
+--------------------+----------------------+
|             roleid |                email |
+--------------------+----------------------+  
| domain.dataViewer  | group1@mycompany.com |
+--------------------+----------------------+
```

**UpdateIamMembersOfIamRoleServiceImpl**

```java
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.mdm.error.basic.DataNotFoundError;
import com.mdm.security.mdmiam.iamrole.persistence.IamRoleRepository;
import com.mdm.security.mdmiam.iamrole.service.mappers.IamRolesMapper;

@Service
public class UpdateIamMembersOfIamRoleServiceImpl
        implements UpdateIamMembersOfIamRoleService {

    private final IamRoleRepository repository;
    private final IamRolesMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(IamRolesMapper.class);

    public UpdateIamMembersOfIamRoleServiceImpl(IamRoleRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateIamMembersOfIamRoleService(IamRole iamRoleDTO,
            Set<IamMember> iamMembers) {

        final Optional<com.mdm.security.mdmiam.iamrole.domain.IamRole> iamRoleDomain = repository
                .findByIdWithItsMembers(iamRoleDTO.getId());

        iamRoleDomain //
                .orElseThrow(() -> new DataNotFoundError("Le rôle {} n'existe pas.",
                        iamRoleDTO.getId())) //
                .setIamRoleMembers(mapper.mapMembers(iamMembers, iamRoleDTO));
    }

}
```

**IamPermission**

```java
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import com.mdm.security.mdmiam.iamrole.domain.IamRole;

@Entity
public class IamPermission {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "iamPermissions")
    private Set<IamRole> iamRoles;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<IamRole> getIamRoles() {
        return iamRoles;
    }

    public void setIamRoles(Set<IamRole> iamRoles) {
        this.iamRoles = iamRoles;
    }

}
```

**IamRole**

```java
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.mdm.security.mdmiam.iampermission.domain.IamPermission;

@Entity
public class IamRole {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "iam_permissions_by_iam_role", //
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "iam_role_id"), //
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "iam_permission_id") //
    )
    private Set<IamPermission> iamPermissions;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<IamRoleMember> iamRoleMembers;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<IamPermission> getIamPermissions() {
        return iamPermissions;
    }

    public void setIamPermissions(Set<IamPermission> iamPermissions) {
        this.iamPermissions = iamPermissions;
    }

    public Set<IamRoleMember> getIamRoleMembers() {
        return iamRoleMembers;
    }

    public void setIamRoleMembers(Set<IamRoleMember> iamRoleMembers) {
        this.iamRoleMembers = iamRoleMembers;
    }

}
```

**IamRoleMember**

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
@IdClass(IamRoleMemberId.class)
public class IamRoleMember {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "iam_member_email")
    private String email;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "iam_role_id")
    private IamRole role;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public IamRole getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(IamRole role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class IamRoleMemberId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2355191029975238555L;

    private String email;

    private String role;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are trying to update from the wrong entity. The owning side among IamRoleMember and IamRole is IamRoleMember. So, any update should be done from IamRoleMember

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Aman but it's working with permissions with the same kind of code (UpdateIamPermissionsOfIamRoleServiceImpl)

Comment: Yes it works since it is the `owning` side in that case. The `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "iamPermissions")
    private Set<IamRole> iamRoles;` shows that this is not the `owning` side. And so you can save `IamRole` from permission, but the inverse works perfectly.

Comment: "Insert" also work

Answer (score 0):

From your entities, check the following:

1. Shows that the class in which this is found is the `owning` side.

   ```
   @ManyToMany
       @JoinTable(name = "iam_permissions_by_iam_role", //
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "iam_role_id"), //
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "iam_permission_id") //
       )
       private Set iamPermissions;
   ```
2. While this is **not**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 private Set<IamRoleMember> iamRoleMembers;
```

https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/

And from your schema, `iam_role_members` and `iam_permissions_by_iam_role` are sharing `iam_roles` `id` which serves as primary key as well as foreign key (though `shared_id` is for `@OneToOne`). So, since it is a primary key, we don't expect duplicates. But, in your code there is `Set<IamRoleMember>`, which in my opinion is **wrong** and it should be just `IamRoleMember` (i.e. with `@OneToOne` correspondence).

The *orphanRemoval* attribute is going to instruct JPA to trigger a remove when entity is no longer referenced by its parent entity.

In the mean while, try to change `Set<IamRoleMember>` to `IamRoleMember` or use orphanRemoval with the current implementation.

Comment: Maybe my JPA model is wrong ?
When we look at the logical model, `iam_role_members` table is like a join table without a dedicated `emails` table.

Comment: `iam_role_members` has a foreign key to `iam_roles`, so saving new `iam_roles` will never affect `iam_role_members`. But, while sacing `iam_role_members` you have to have an `iam_roles` to associate with. So, it doesn't have a sense to update from `iam_roles`.

Comment: JPA is able to create `iam_role_members` when I create the role (see code and logs: https://gist.github.com/pierrefevrier/cbf0ad0c0ebe5e5dd661d0f0a2483b78).
Add new members to collection also work. The only thing that doesn't work is deleting members from collection.

Comment: I have added a link in the answer, it will give you a good view.

Comment: Thanks for the link, as @Vlad Mihalcea said in this article https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/ (search One-To-Many title), cascading One-To-Many relation seems to be something allowed by JPA

Comment: `orphanRemoval = true` seems to be done for the propose I'm looking for. I think the problem comes from the way I implement PK/FK in `IamRoleMember` and `IamRoleMemberId`

Comment: @pierrefevrier I have edited the answer to add a bit of a detail on how it should be implemented.

Comment: I though it was the propose of `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to remove children when the owning entity is deleted ?

Comment: You are right, check the following link for their particular difference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813341/what-is-the-difference-between-cascadetype-remove-and-orphanremoval-in-jpa