# Delete both parent and child in @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity called `itineraryTraveller`, and every `itineraryTraveller` can have many `flightEntity`. When I try to delete an `itineraryTraveller` (parent),  from the database, I get this error message:

```
a foreign key constraint fails (`pquino01db`.`ITINERARYTRAVELLER_FLIGHTENTITY`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ITINERARYTRAVELLER_FLIGHTENTITY_flights_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`flights_ID`) REFERENCES `FLIGHTENTITY` (`ID`))"
```

Here is my `itineraryTraveller` entity:

```
@Entity
public class itineraryTraveller implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<flightEntity> flights;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date departureDate;

    private String departureLocation;
    private String arrivalLocation;
    private double cost;
    private char status;
    private ArrayList<String> stops;
    private String stopPrint;
    private String userName;
    private int iden;

    // ...
}
```

And the `flightEntity` looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class flightEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date departureDate;

    private String airlineCode;
    private String flightNumber;
    private String departureLocation;
    private String arrivalLocation;
    private double businessCost;
    private double economyCost;
    private int numBusinessSeats;
    private int numEconomySeats;

    // ...
}
```

Can someone see the problem? I think my `@OneToMany` annotation might be missing something, but I'm not sure what. I want to delete both the parent and child at the same time.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate to do the work?

Comment: JPA Ecliplse Link with glassfish

Comment: Ok thanks, my suggestion is probably irrelevant, however you should check which type of CascadeType you use, I know with Hibernate you should use Hibernate's perhaps glassfish has a similar issue? Check here: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA OneToMany not deleting child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011519/jpa-onetomany-not-deleting-child)

Comment: In the above mentioned link appears an specific answer for Eclipse Link: @PrivateOwned annotation. http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_privateowned.htm

Comment: I've read those links thanks, but it does not find the @CascadeOnDelete. it says "cannot find symbol". HELP

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar how can I fix that then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship between the two entities is unidirectional as there is no mapping from `flightEntity` back to `itineraryTraveller` entity as you do not have a `@JoinColumn` on your `flightEntity`. There can be one of the following solutions for your problem:

1. Add a `@ManyToOne` annotation on the `flightEntity` as follows:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class flightEntity implements Serializable {
      // ....

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="<name_of_foreignkey_column>")
      private itineraryTraveller traveller;

      // ...
   }
   ```

   And you have to add a `mappedBy` attribute to your `@OneToMany` annotation:

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="traveller", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   ```

   Thereby making the relationship between the entities bidirectional.

This one can solve the problem if you already have tables in the database with a foreign key relationship.

2. Use `@JoinTable` annotation on the `@OneToMany` annotation:

   ```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinTable(name="<join_table_name>", joinColumns=@JoinColumn("TRAVELLER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn("FLIGHT_ID"))
   private List<flightEntity> flights;
   ```

(The names of the columns are considered to be examples, and can be changed.)

This last mapping is useful if you don't have tables in the database with foreign key column defined, and it will create a new table as an association between the tables; which is normally the case in a many-to-many relationships.

If it is possible use `@ManyToOne` annotation on the flights entity. This is normal way of mapping a one-to-many relationships.

Lastly, there are conventions in Java that state class names should begin with a capital letter. So I would rename the entity names to `Flight` and `ItineraryTraveller`.

Comment: thanks!! I am using the 2 solution. But it does not find "TRAVELLER_ID", neither "FLIGHT_ID". Where should I set these columns names?

Comment: `TRAVELLER_ID` and `FLIGH_ID` are the names I chose. But in your case you have to look for the correct column names in your database. Do you have an association table containing the primary keys of both tables?

Comment: the thing is that I want my application to automatically create all tables in the database. So I rather not manipulate from database. As when first deployed the application, those tables would not already exist

Comment: and btw my objective is to delete a FlightEntity from db, then automatically delete all ItineraryTravellers that contain that flight inside their property list of flights

Comment: I thought you have already tables in the database. If you want to create all the tables automatically, it doesn't matter which way you choose. You have only to tell your JPA provider to generate the tables, and indeed only the first time you deploy your application.

Comment: and then what TRAVELLED_ID and FLIGHT_ID names should I write?

Comment: I am not sure that I understood you; if not leave me a comment. (Then tomorrow). If you choose to use these names `TRAVELLED_ID` should match the `ID` column of the `itineraryTraveller` table and `FLIGHT_ID` matches the `ID` column of the `flightEntity` in the join table.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in some cases the @JoinColumn on the child object must have insertable = false and  updatable = false like this:
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)

```
public class User {
   private List<UserRole>   roles;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
   public List<UserRole> getRoles() {
      return this.roles;
   }
   public void setRoles(List<UserRole> roles) {
       this.roles = roles;
   }

}

public class UserRole {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;
}
```